# PostgreSQL: Rules and serial attributes

Tags: postgresql, rules

This is a basic schema of my PostgreSQL database:

```
create table client(numclient serial not null,
                    age int not null,
                    amountDue decimal(10,2) not null default 0.0,

                primary key (numclient) );

create table payment(   numpayment serial not null,
                        amountPaid decimal(10,2) not null default 0.0,
                        numclient int not null,
                    primary key (numpayment),
                    foreign key (numclient) references client
                        on delete cascade );

create or replace rule on_insert_client as on insert to client
do also insert into payment(numclient) values(new.numclient);
```

This works fine but when I want to insert an element into the table client by doing:

```
insert into client(age) values (25);
```

I get this error message:

ERROR:  insert or update on table "payment" violates foreign key constraint "payment_numclient_fkey"

DETAIL:  Key (numclient)=(2) is not present in table "client".

If I understand well, there is an error because it tries to insert a new row in the table payment before inserting the row in the table client. However, when I use this:

```
insert into client(numclient, amountDue, age) values (4, 0.0, 25);
```

It works fine. However, this is quite restrictive because the numclient is not a serial attribute anymore if I have to choose the value of the attribute myself.

So it seems the problem comes from the default serial attribute that creates the value after the execution of the rule. Is there any trick to bypass this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no `numToken`  column in both tables.

Comment: Sorry, I also use the numToken attribute in my project. It is numclient of course. I edited the question.

Comment: It looks like case in first comment [Rule](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/rules-update.html): `won't work if foo.id is a serial (and foo_id REFERENCES foos ofcourse) because nextval() is evaluated twice` and workaround with `SEQUENCE` instead of `SERIAL`. But then it won't work with inserting multimple values at once. Related and possible duplicate: **[PostgreSQL's rules and nextval()/serial problem (very PostgreSQL-specific)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324377/postgresqls-rules-and-nextval-serial-problem-very-postgresql-specific)**